# i cant get this AJAX jquery tutorial to work. wont load page 

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

my pages wont load. can anyone suggest what is wrong? I tried changing the file path to the different files in case that was what was causing the problem. but still none of them are loading. what should happen is that when the user clicks the link, the page should be loaded inside the div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> jquery example</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="menu_top" href="pages/home1.php">Home</a>/
<a class="menu_top" href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>/
<a class="menu_top" href="contact.php">Contact</a>

<div id="#content_area"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content_area').load($('.menu_top:first').attr('href'));
});

$('.menu_top').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    alert('clicked');
    $('#content_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
    return false;
});​
```

I am able to see the alert when i click on the .menu_top element. but it wont load it on the page. i tried renaming the files to .html and it still wont worl. i am running on a xammp local host, and that seems to work fine for everything else. i checked my console for errors and it doesnt return any errors.

i just finished some of the previous ajax tutorials and they loaded the data without any problems, so i ruled out that it was something concerning the local host.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log($('.menu_top:first'));` ?

Comment: The best way would be to accept Jake's answer about the hash or post your own and accept it, not to edit the title of your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the Hash from your ID :)

`<div id="#content_area"></div>`

to

`<div id="content_area"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `$('.menu_top:first-child')`

Comment: i fixed the first-child but my pages still arent loading into the div. the jquery file is in the correct directory (same as a index). i am really racking my brain to figure out what is wrong. i am hoping that i am just made a typo. but nothing seems to be appearing to be wrong.

Comment: Have you verified that the ajax request is returning a response?  Does the output of `console.log($('.menu_top:first-child'));` show the element is being shown on the page?

Comment: i solved the issue. it was a typo with an extra hashtag on the <div id="#content"></div> i didnt need a hashtag there